# How to convert the below code into .netcore 6.0 & Episerver CMS 12

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

The below code giving some errors. Could you please help us to upgrade to .netcore 6.0

```cs
 private static string Fingerprint(string rootRelativePath, string extension)
 {
     if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] != null)
     {
         return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
     }
     // Build path
     var absolute = "~" + rootRelativePath;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
     {
         absolute = absolute + "." + extension;
     }
     absolute = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(absolute);

     Debug.Assert(absolute != null, "absolute != null");
     var date = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute);
     var index = rootRelativePath.LastIndexOf('/');

     var result = rootRelativePath.Insert(index, "/v-" + date.Ticks);
     HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, result, new CacheDependency(absolute));

     return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
 }
```

Errors

1. The name 'HttpRuntime' does not exist in the current context
2. The name 'HostingEnvironment' does not exist in the current context
3. The type or namespace name 'CacheDependency' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Working functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo you could follow:

```
public static class ApiServices
{
    private static IMemoryCache _cache;
    private static IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public static void Initialize(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
        _env = env;
    }
    private static string Fingerprint(string rootRelativePath, string extension)
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(rootRelativePath, out string cachedValue))
        {
            return cachedValue;
        }    
        // Build path
        var absolute = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, rootRelativePath.TrimStart('~', '/'));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            absolute = absolute + "." + extension;
        }

        Debug.Assert(absolute != null, "absolute != null");
        var date = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute);
        var index = rootRelativePath.LastIndexOf('/');

        var result = rootRelativePath.Insert(index, "/v-" + date.Ticks);
        _cache.Set(rootRelativePath, result, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(10) // or other expiration strategy
        });   
        return result;
    }            
}
```

- `IMemoryCache` is used for caching.
- `IWebHostEnvironment` is used to get the web root path.

You need to manually initialize the `ApiServices` with an `IMemoryCache` instance and `IWebHostEnvironment` in Program.cs in .NET 6:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();  
var app = builder. Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
ApiServices.Initialize(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>(), app.Environment);

// Other middleware...

app.Run();
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a [code sample](https://stefanolsen.com/posts/cache-busting-2-0-an-update-for-asp-net-core/) of a similar method for .NET 5 and up. Hope this can help.

Comment: Please add all details *inside*  the answer